# argument null exception was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#

I am getting following error.

argument null exception was unhandled by user code.
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value

in the below code at Bold place.

```
public static void InsertIntoCache(string cacheKey, object value)
{
    HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(cacheKey, value, null, DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(0, CacheDuration, 0)), **Cache.NoSlidingExpiration**, CacheItemPriority.Default,null);
}
```

please help me on this.

Comment: Pretty sure it can't be at the location you're pointing out. `Cache` is set up by the ASP .NET runtime, and the property is a enumerated value for `DateTime`. Is your variable `value` equal to `null`?

Answer (score 2):

The method signature for `Cache.Insert()` is (taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05kd8d77%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)):

```
public void Insert (
string key,
Object value,
CacheDependency dependencies,
DateTime absoluteExpiration,
TimeSpan slidingExpiration,
CacheItemPriority priority,
CacheItemRemovedCallback onRemoveCallback
)
```

The error is telling you that `value`, which is the 2nd parameter in the `.Insert()` method, can not be null.  That means that your method is being called with null as the 2nd parameter, like:

```
InsertIntoCache("some_key", null);  // this will throw an exception.
```

Basically, you can not cache 'null' as a value. If you scroll down in [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05kd8d77%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to "Exceptions", it states that Insert() will throw a `ArgumentNullException` when:

> The key or value parameter is a null reference